# Timeline Charts like Github.com

Tags: javascript, charts, github

Has anyone seen an open-source library that produces charts similar to Github.com's commit timeline charts? Check out [this profile](http://github.com/jnunemaker) (picked one at random) and note the bar graphs below each project.

I've been trying to dominate Flot into behaving correctly but it just doesn't have the flexibility of formatting options to come up with a decent clone. Personally, I'd prefer a Javascript implementation but I'm open to looking at server-side stuff as well.

Definitely has to be a stand-alone implementation, the application is headed to a network separated from the Internet, so Google Charts API is out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using [jQuery Sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/). You'll need to create two separate graphs and position them on top of one another (one for the blue bars, another for the gray bars). You'll also need to make the dotted line/legend an image, but github also uses an image for that.

Here are some decent values to get you started:

[image: Example sparkline values]

EDIT: I originally overlapped two separate sparklines with relative positioning, but it would be better to use the "composite" option to draw two graphs on the same canvas.